# Base 64 encoding random behaviour UIImage

Tags: iphone, encoding, uiimage

I am sending an image to the server by converting the NSData object into an NSString object using Base64 scheme by using....

```
 NSData *imgData=UIImagePNGRepresentation([objCP userImage]);
 NSString *encodedString=[Base64Coder encodeData:imgData];
```

I am observing a random behavior....sometimes I get "==" in the encoded string at the end of the string and image does not uploaded.There may be some other characters also in between the string.If I do not get these characters at the end...image gets uploaded.
To overcome this...I also used this method to convert these characters into valid(assumed to be accepted)::

```
-(NSString *)urlEncodedVersion:(NSString *)strString
{ 
    NSMutableString *strTemp = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@",strString] ;
    NSArray *escapeChars = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@";",@"?",@":",@"@", @"&",@"=",@"+",@"$",@",", @"[",@"]",@"#",@"!",@"’",@"(", @")",@"*",@" ",nil];

    NSArray *replaceChars = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: @"%3B",@"%3F",@"%3A",
                             @"%40",@"%26",@"%3D", @"%2B",@"%24",@"%2C",@"%5B",@"%5D", @"%23",@"%21",@"%27", @"%28",@"%29",@"%2A",@"%20",nil];

    //NSMutableString *tempStr = [[self mutableCopy] autorelease]; 
    for(int i = 0; i < [escapeChars count]; i++)
    {
        [strTemp replaceOccurrencesOfString:[escapeChars objectAtIndex:i] withString:[replaceChars objectAtIndex:i] options:NSLiteralSearch range:NSMakeRange(0,[strTemp length])];
    } 
    return strTemp;
}
```

but it is also not serving.

**This is my whole post body::**

```
-(void)uploadProfileInfo:(CreateProfile *)objCP
{

    NSData *imgData=UIImagePNGRepresentation([objCP userImage]);
    NSString *encodedString=[Base64Coder encodeData:imgData];

    NSString *refinedString=[self urlEncodedVersion:encodedString];

    NSString *soapMessage = [NSString stringWithFormat:

                             @"<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>\n"
                             "<soapenv:Envelope \n"
                             "xmlns:soapenv=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\" \n"
                             "xmlns:tem=\"http://tempuri.org/\" \n"
                             "xmlns:wcf=\"http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/NextToMe_BusinessEntity\"> \n"
                             "<soapenv:Header/>\n"
                             "<soapenv:Body>\n"
                             "<tem:CreateProfile>\n"

                             "<tem:objUser>\n"

                             "<wcf:Email>%@</wcf:Email>\n"

                             "<wcf:Mode>%@</wcf:Mode> \n"

                             "<wcf:Name>%@</wcf:Name>\n"

                             "<wcf:ProfileImage>%@</wcf:ProfileImage>\n"

                             "<wcf:RequestDateTime>%@</wcf:RequestDateTime>\n"

                             "<wcf:Status>%@</wcf:Status>\n"

                             "<wcf:StatusSpecified>%@</wcf:StatusSpecified>\n"

                             "<wcf:UDID>%@</wcf:UDID>\n"

                             "</tem:objUser>\n"

                             "</tem:CreateProfile>\n"

                             "</soapenv:Body>\n"

                             "</soapenv:Envelope>\n",[objCP email],[objCP mode],[objCP name],encodedString,@"",[objCP status],[objCP statusSpecified],[objCP UDID]];





    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:kBaseURL];               
    NSMutableURLRequest *theRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];             
    NSString *msgLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [soapMessage length]];          
    [theRequest addValue: @"text/xml; charset=utf-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];       
    [theRequest addValue: @"http://tempuri.org/XXXX/CreateProfile" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Soapaction"];
    [theRequest addValue: msgLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
    [theRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];     
    [theRequest setHTTPBody: [soapMessage dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    NSURLConnection *theConnection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:theRequest delegate:self];

    if( theConnection )
    {
        webData = [[NSMutableData data] retain];
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"The Connection is NULL");
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The = characters you see at the end are padding. This is according to [RFC4648](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4648.txt) 3.2. Padding of Encoded Data. The other end should be able to digest that. Apparently that is not happening. You should compare the behavior with a third party library to check whether the encoding or decoding is wrong.  If you can make it work removing the padding, then good for you, but that's a fault in the decoding library.

Comment: If i hard code any image kept in the bundle like this
NSData *imgData=UIImagePNGRepresentation([UIImage imageNamed:@"abc.png" ]);...I never get this padding...why it is random??

Comment: It's not random - it will depend on the data and your encoding algorithm.